# What does "burst" mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

Source : http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/man-shares-photo-that-perfectly-shows-why-he-loves-his-hardworking-girlfriend_5697bf18e4b0ce496423637b

In the article ;

> This is how I found her tonight. I'm so proud of this woman I could burst.

I am fine with this sentence except the word burst, what could it mean?

Also in the same article :

> "I'm gonna take all of y'alls advice and marry the sh*t out of her," he wrote.

What does the phrase (the sh*t out of her) mean? Also, how polite is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more of an informal way of speaking. To *"burst"* implies (in this context) :

> **to be full as if to the bursting point with pride.**

This simply means that the speaker is super proud of his hardworking girlfriend and his feeling of pride towards her is very high, and for the same he has used *"burst"* to describe the level of pride he has towards her. This feeling fills him up and he feels like he may explode (metaphorically, of course).

*"To marry the sh*t out of her..."* simply means to marry her and keep her very happy. This is a common usage, especially in American English. Similar sentences would be:

> I'm going to scare the sh*t out of them this Halloween.

This is just to create an emphatic impact. There is specific meaning and sh*t has got nothing to do with the actual concept.

Another usage is to replace *'sh*t'* with *'hell'* or *'bejesus'* :

> I'm going to scare the hell/ bejesus out of them this Halloween.

This simply means : *'to make one feel extremely frightened'*.

**These are highly informal and never to be used formally. It may come off as very rude or offensive to many people.**

**NOTE:** *'scare the sh*t out of someone'* is commonly used. *'Marry the sh*t out of her'* is an analogy to the same, but isn't used widely (it is content-specific). There are many ways you can recreate it, based on the context.

Comment: I think it's important to say that "scare the s**t out of" is common usage, "marry the s**t out of" is an analogy to this, but is not itself common.

Answer (score 2):

*To burst* means to explode.

*So X I could burst* is an idiom meaning that you feel X very very strongly.  It doesn't usually mean you will explode.  However, sometimes X can be "full" as in "eaten too much," in which case it might mean that a little.

*X the sh_t out of Y* basically means to do X to Y the maximum extent possible.  Where X is something that is binary (e.g. you either marry someone or don't), it means you want to do X very, very much.  The phrase falls in the category of "curse words" - it can be vulgar but sometimes is just used to express something very strongly.  Avoid in polite company and do not use in business or formal settings.

Answer (score 0):

1. Burst could be short for [**burst into tears**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/burst+into+tears) which means:

> to begin to cry suddenly: '*After the last notes of her song, the audience burst into tears, such was its beauty and tenderness. The children burst into tears on hearing of the death of their dog*'.

[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs]

The writer feels so sorry and pround to see her sleeping that way that he wants to cry feeling sympathy and pride at the same time.

To [burst](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/burst) literally means:

> break open or apart suddenly or violently especially as a result of
>   an impact or internal pressure
>
> feel a very strong or irrepressible emotion or impulse:

[Oxford Online Dictionary].

To burst could mean a few different things, but one thing is he is full of pride and emotion.

2. **The sxxt out of** in "marry the sxxt out of her" is an idiomatic expression to **intensify** the verb *marry*. Please see the related question, [How to understand “bomb the expletive out of something”? Is that an idiomatic expression?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74106/how-to-understand-bomb-the-expletive-out-of-something-is-that-an-idiomatic-ex).

The link contains very similar expressions, but "marry the sh*t out of her" is not a very common expression compared with other expressions in the link.

Comment: What's the source for your assertion that "burst" is short for "burst into tears"?  I've never heard it to imply that.

Comment: @stangdon To **burst** literally means break open or apart suddenly or violently especially as a result of an impact or internal pressure (Oxford definition). Now, burst could mean different things. One thing is he is full of emotion internally and it is about to explode. I will edit the post.